# play framework- how to send post request using java code in play framework

Tags: java, playframework

Currently I'm switching to play framework to develop but I'm new to this wonderful framework.
I just want to send a post request to remote server and get response.

If I use Jersey, it would be quite easy, just like this:

```
WebResource resource = client.resource("http://myfirstUrl");
 resource.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
 Form form = new Form();
 form.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
 form.add("client_id", "myclientId");
 form.add("client_secret", "mysecret");
 form.add("code", "mycode");
 form.add("redirect_uri", "http://mysecondUrl");       
 String msg = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(String.class, form);
```

and then I can get the msg which is what I want.

But in Play framework, I cannot find any libs to send such post request. I believe this should be a very simple feature and Play should have integrated it. I've tried to search and found most use case are about the Form in view leve. Could anyone give me some help or examples? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check the zentasks example from play: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaGuide1. The play framework you have downloaded should contains the source code of this example. It includes several features including form handling.

Comment: Hi Tom, I have just browsed the zentask example source code, unfortunately, I didn't find any similar use cases to send a post request in java code. I wonder I have to integrate the Jersey to play to achieve such a small feature...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Play WS API for making asynchronous HTTP Calls within your Play application. First you should add `javaWs` as a dependency.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaWs
)
```

Then making HTTP POST Requests are as simple as;

```
WS.url("http://myposttarget.com")
 .setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 .post("key1=value1&key2=value2");
```

`post()` and other http methods returns a `F.Promise<WSResponse>` object which is something inherited from Play Scala to Play Java. Basically it is the underlying mechanism of asynchronous calls. You  can process and get the result of your request as follows:

```
Promise<String> promise = WS.url("http://myposttarget.com")
 .setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 .post("key1=value1&key2=value2")
 .map(
    new Function<WSResponse, String>() {
        public String apply(WSResponse response) {
            String result = response.getBody();
            return result;
        }
    }
);
```

Finally obtained `promise` object is a wrapper around a `String` object in our case. And you can get the wrapped `String` as:

```
long timeout = 1000l;// 1 sec might be too many for most cases!
String result = promise.get(timeout);
```

`timeout` is the waiting time until this asynchronous request will be considered as failed.

For much more detailed explanation and more advanced use cases checkout the documentation and javadocs.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaWS

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/index.html